# TabActivity destroy Activity of each tab when tab changed

Tags: android, tabbar

Problem in TabActivity
I have three tabs in my app and every one is different activity.
In the first tab I have a textfield and listview through which user search
But after the search when the tab is changed by the user and come back again to
The search tab then the list and textbox are cleared.

But I want to be still populates.
What tab bar do with activity destroy? Stop? Pause? I don’t know 
Is there any way to do this 
Thanks.

```
public class MainTab extends TabActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);            

        TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
        TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");

        /* TabSpec setIndicator() is used to set name for the tab. */
        /* TabSpec setContent() is used to set content for a particular tab. */
        firstTabSpec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search)).setContent(new Intent(this,Search.class));
        secondTabSpec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.manager)).setContent(new Intent(this,Manager.class));
        thirdTabSpec.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings)).setContent(new Intent(this,Settings.class));

        tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(thirdTabSpec);
…………………
```

the code is same as normal tabbar required....
it will be difficult if we save the instance manually of every class i have a lot of data in the activities

Comment: Read up on [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and [Saving Persistent State](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState)

Comment: In TabActivity when tab changes previous activity get paused. i.e. onPause() method get called. Show your code.

Comment: I have a Edittextbox and Listview when user write text in edittext then click the button search and list was then populated if the user click another tab and come back then both the edittext and listview was cleared. why they not save there instance?????????

Comment: Post your code so we can help you...

Comment: post the code what you have in 1st tab.

Answer (score 5):

Replace your following code,

```
TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
```

with these,

```
TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid2");
TabSpec thirdTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid3");
```

Comment: My collegue and I needed a minute to see the difference. For the benefit of others: in the first, all 3 specs use "tid1"